# Using splinter how can I click this link / button

Tags: python, splinter

The HTML on the page has a button formatted like this:

```
    <span class="v-button-caption">Ändern</span>
```

I have been googling around and looking at other posts on here and none helped :/

Any tips? Thanks!

Can provide more info if need be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeFbD.png

Sorry couldnt figure out how to include pictures here a tad confusing!

Answer (score 0):

newButton = browser.find_by_id('postalischeAdressenPflegen').click()
I had to find another element and click the element.